# PDO + MsSQL + freetds = wrong characters in INSERT queries

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, freetds, bindvalue

I've noticed a problem during SELECT queries in my internal project, regarding utf8 characters (šđčćž). After I'd fixed problem regarding freetds definition for charset and version in freetds.conf, I've started to receive right characters when I run SELECT queries.

But! Now I'm experiencing problem regarding INSERT/UPDATE queries and with SELECT query when I try to search fields with some of those characters (šđčćž), and that's only with PDO bindValue method.

For example, this is my code:

```
try {
$pdo = new \PDO(
      "dblib:host=$host:$port;dbname=$database",
      "$username",
      "$password"
   );
   $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $e) {
   echo "There was a problem connecting. " . $e->getMessage();
}
```

When I try insert values with following code, inserted values in database are right:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES (2, 'Beriša');";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->execute();

//Result:
//2 Beriša
```

But, after using bindValue method (which I must use, as I work with Symfony2), problem happens:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO dbo.TABLE (ID, NAME) VALUES (?, ?);";
$statement = $pdo->prepare($query);
$statement->bindValue(1, 2, \PDO::PARAM_INT);
$statement->bindValue(2, 'Beriša', \PDO::PARAM_STR);
$statement->execute();

//Result:
//2 BeriĹˇa
```

Bellow, you can find my current freetds configuration:

```
[global]
    tds version = 8.0
    text size = 20971520
    client charset = UTF-8
```

Database charset coalition is Croatian_CI_AS. Unfortunately, I can't change that, as it's old database, designed to work with old application, and for that application I'm working on web presentation.

Comment: pass utf8 in the connection's dsn

Comment: If you think about: 
$pdo = new \PDO(
        "dblib:host=$host:$port;dbname=$database;charset=utf8",
        "$username",
        "$password"
    );

Already tired and it doesn't help.

Comment: @MarkoMilojevic I cannot reproduce your issue, it works for me, perhaps this will help `$statement->bindValue(2, utf8_encode('Beriša'), \PDO::PARAM_STR);`

Comment: @meda I've tried it, but no results. Still, similar solution gave me result (see answer bellow). Perhaps, you can find cleaner solution (considering answer bellow as an idea).

Comment: What data type did you use in SQL server

Comment: In this case, varchar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a solution after some time. It's not a perfect one, as I need to process each value (it's small fix for code, but still not clean enough). If anyone has another idea to make this one better, post it, pls.

```
$statement->bindValue(2, iconv('utf-8', 'Windows-1252', 'Beriša'), \PDO::PARAM_STR);
```